# Task.Wait() deadlocks Xamarin.iOS NUnit runner

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin.ios, nunit, xamarin

I have a class with some methods like this:

```
private Task Sleep()
{
    return Task.Delay(SleepDuration);
}

public async Task<User> Login(string username, string password)
{
    await Sleep();

    return new User { Id = 1, Username = username };
}
```

Note, `SleepDuration` is set to 0 during my tests.

If I call the following in an iOS NUnit project test:

`myClass.Login("username", "password").Wait();`

The test runner's UI pauses and never completes. If I add break points, the code never reaches the line after the `await`. The same test works fine running in the standard NUnit runner in a .Net 4.5 Mono project. It also works fine in my application, although I never call `Wait` and always use async/await.

Any ideas? Is there something else I can use instead of `Task.Delay` to prevent the deadlock? I tried `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { })` already.

Answer (score 2):

Modern versions of NUnit supply a `SynchronizationContext` for their unit tests so that they can support `async void` unit tests.

It's quite likely that this context is causing a deadlock when you block on asynchronous code (i.e., `Wait`). I have a blog post that [describes the interaction in detail](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Note that this deadlock only happens if `Task.Delay` returns an `Task` that is not yet completed; for extremely short delays, there's a race condition whether the `Task` is completed or not by the time it hits the `Wait`.

I recommend that you use `await` in your unit test, and make your test method `async Task`.

Comment: I'm using the NUnit project template for Xamarin.iOS, it uses a version of NUnit Lite (via MonoTouch.NUnitLite) and doesn't support async tests. It works fine in a normal Mono/.Net 4.5 NUnit project even with NUnit 2.6.0. But I think 2.6.2 is required for async tests.

Comment: Ok, your comment on an unfinished task led me to a workaround. I used `Task.FromResult(true)` instead of `Task.Delay(0)`, but I still think this is a bug in Xamarin.iOS's version of NUnit since everything works fine in the standard Mono NUnit project.

Comment: @jonathanpeppers XI 7.0 ships with NUnitlite 0.9 which supports async tests.

Comment: I'll try an async test and let you know.

Comment: Async works on iOS, but not in the NUnit runner in Xamarin Studio. We kind of want both to work. If I use async/await it works on iOS, and calling `Wait()` on the `Task` works in the Mono project. Calling `Wait()` also works well in MsTest in Visual Studio, which is normally what I've always done.